# Dimension of irreducible projective algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $Y \subset P^n(\Bbb{C}$) is
an irreducible projective algebraic set, then how to show that  dim$Y$ is equal to the minimum $r \in \Bbb{ N }$ such that there
exists a linear subspace $S_{n-r-1} \subset P^n(\Bbb{C}$) with  $S_{n-r-1}\cap X=\emptyset$. It will be helpful if i get a reference for this fact.

Comment: To answer this question, first you must specify which definition of dimension you are using.

Comment: my definition of dimension of X is the largest length of chain of irreducible closed subsets of X.

Comment: Dear abc, I think this should be discussed in section 7 of Ch. I of Hartshorne (which discusses some basic results on intersections, degrees, and so on).  Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Lemma 3.2 of chapter VII (page 122) of [Algebraic Geometry, An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848000553) by Perrin.